# Dual boot within the same HDD

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade

I am afraid to do that, because at first both of my Operating systems crashed whenever `I wanted to upgrade my` **(windows 7 to 10 OS)** as a result I had to use rescue boot to fix the problem since both OS's weren't loaded from the beginning when the Laptop is booting up.

What can I do to make sure that Ubuntu is not affected during the Windows upgrade process?

Comment: Install Ubuntu _after_ the upgrade?

Comment: Okay Thanks it works perfectly .

Comment: But what if there comes a new windows upgrade again?